# Docker - Access host /proc

Tags: linux, docker, virtualization

This is a duplicate of a [post](https://forums.docker.com/t/access-host-proc/40604) I have created in the docker forum. Thus I am going to close this / the other one once this problem is solved. But since no one answers in the docker forum and my problem persists, I'll post it again, looking forward to get an answer.

I would like to expose a server monitoring app as a docker container. The app I have written relies on /proc to read system information like CPU utilization or disk stats. Thus I have to forward the information provided in hosts /proc virtual file system to my docker container.

So I made a simple image (using the first or second intro on docker website: [Link](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/part2/#the-app-itself)) and started it:

```
docker run -v=/proc:/host/proc:ro -d hostfiletest
```

Assuming the running container could read from /host/proc to obtain information about the host system.

I fired up a console inside the container to check:

```
docker exec -it {one of the funny names the container get} bash
```

And checked the content of /host/proc.

Easiest way to check it was getting the content of /host/proc/sys/kernel/hostname - that should yield the hostname of the vm I am working on.
But I get the hostname of the container, while /host/proc/uptime gets me the correct uptime of the vm.

Do I miss something here? Maybe something conceptual?

Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be running on Linux 4.4.0-97-generic (VM)

Update:

I found several articles describing how to run a specific monitoring app inside a containing using the same approach I mentioned above.

Update:

Just tried using an existing Ubuntu image - same behavior. Running the image privileged and with pid=host doesn't help.

Greetings
Peepe

Comment: Check https://hub.docker.com/r/frapsoft/atop/ and `docker run --pid=host`

Comment: Still the same problem. /prochost/sys/kernel/hostname yields the container host name as well as /prochost/mounts yields container mounts.

Answer (score 5):

The reason of this problem is that `/proc` is not a normal filesystem. According to [procfs](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Procfs), it is like an interface to access some kernel data and system information. This interface provides a file-like structure, so it can make people misunderstand that it is a normal directory. 
Files in `/proc` are also not normal files. They are empty (size = 0). You can check by yourself.

```
$ stat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname 
File: /proc/sys/kernel/hostname
Size: 0             Blocks: 0          IO Block: 1024   regular empty file
```

So the file doesn't hold any data, but when you read the file, the kernel will dynamically return to you a corresponding system information.

To answer your question, `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname` is just an interface to access the hostname. And depending on where you access that interface, on the host or on the container, you will get the corresponding hostname. This is also applied when you use bind mount `-v /proc:/hosts/proc:ro`, since bind mount will provide an alternative view of `/proc`. If you call the interface `/hosts/proc/sys/kernel/hostname`, the kernel will return the hostname of the box where you are in (the container).

In short, think about`/proc/sys/kernel/hostname` as a mirror, if your host stands in front of it, it will reflect the host. If it is the container, it will reflect the container.

---

Answer (score 3):

I know its a few months later no but I came across the same problem today.

In my case I was using `psutil` in Python to read disk stats of the hosts from inside a docker container.

The solution was to mount the **whole** host files system as read only into the docker container with `-v /:/rootfs:ro` and specify the path to proc as `psutil.PROCFS_PATH = '/rootfs/proc'`.

Now the `psutil.disk_partitions()` lists all partitions from the host files system. As the hostname is also contained within the proc hierarchy, I guess this also works for other host system information as long the the retrieving command points to `/rootsfs/proc`.