# Access to full /proc in Docker container

Tags: linux, docker

By default, Docker hides several files and directories of the container's `/proc` by mounting something over it:

```
$ docker run ubuntu:bionic findmnt -R /proc
TARGET                SOURCE              FSTYPE OPTIONS
/proc                 proc                proc   rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
|-/proc/bus           proc[/bus]          proc   ro,relatime
|-/proc/fs            proc[/fs]           proc   ro,relatime
|-/proc/irq           proc[/irq]          proc   ro,relatime
|-/proc/sys           proc[/sys]          proc   ro,relatime
|-/proc/sysrq-trigger proc[/sysrq-trigger]
|                                         proc   ro,relatime
|-/proc/asound        tmpfs               tmpfs  ro,relatime
|-/proc/acpi          tmpfs               tmpfs  ro,relatime
|-/proc/kcore         tmpfs[/null]        tmpfs  rw,nosuid,size=65536k,mode=755
|-/proc/keys          tmpfs[/null]        tmpfs  rw,nosuid,size=65536k,mode=755
|-/proc/timer_list    tmpfs[/null]        tmpfs  rw,nosuid,size=65536k,mode=755
|-/proc/sched_debug   tmpfs[/null]        tmpfs  rw,nosuid,size=65536k,mode=755
`-/proc/scsi          tmpfs               tmpfs  ro,relatime
```

How can I disable this behavior in Docker (currently using version 18.09)?
I need access to a `proc` instance without any mounts over it, otherwise nested containers (e.g., with `unshare`) fail because a kernel protection kicks in. One can see this with the following command:

```
docker run -it --security-opt="seccomp=unconfined" --cap-drop=all ubuntu:bionic unshare --fork --user --pid --mount --mount-proc --setgroups deny --map-root-user --propagation unchanged /bin/bash
```

This fails with `unshare: mount /proc failed: Permission denied` because of the mounts that are on top of `/proc`, and would work if Docker would not create these mounts.

I know that `--privileged` provides full access to `/proc`:

```
$ docker run --privileged ubuntu:bionic findmnt -R /proc
TARGET SOURCE FSTYPE OPTIONS
/proc  proc   proc   rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
```

However, `--privileged` gives the container much more permissions (capabilities, device access, etc.) and I do not want this. I only need full access to `/proc`.

It would also be ok for me to have the `proc` file system mounted twice in the container, if one of the mounts does not have the overlapping mounts. Unfortunately, using `--volume /proc:/proc2` mounts the host's `/proc` in the container, and I need the container's `/proc`. (Because of this, this questions is not a duplicate of [Docker - Access host /proc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47072586/docker-access-host-proc)).

**Summary**: How to get a fully visible `/proc` instance of the container's `proc` file system in a Docker container without using `--privileged`?

Comment: Have you tried using `--cap-add=SYS_ADMIN` (and `--security-opt apparmor:unconfined`) as suggested by [this GitHub comment](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/5254#issuecomment-603342582)?

Comment: @Delthas I tried now, and (as expected) it does not work. The capabilities are not the problem, it even works with `--privileged --cap-drop=ALL`. One does not need any capability to create a new namespace and mount something within the namespace (note that the GitHub comment talks about a case without additional namespaces). The problem is that Docker hides `/proc` except when using `--privileged`.

Comment: Hi @PhilippWendler, Did you find any solution? I am also facing a similar kind of problem.

Comment: @Mahesh Unfortunately no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was already [implemented in Docker 3 years ago](https://github.com/docker/cli/pull/1808) for version 19.03, the solution is

```
--security-opt systempaths=unconfined
```

Unfortunately, it remains undocumented so far.

Note that it does not only allow access to unrestricted `/proc` but also to some more directories, e.g., `/sys/firmware`. But it should still be more restrictive than `--privileged`.

Comment: If you continue to see the error `open /proc/sys/kernel/domainname: permission denied: unknown`, remove user namespace remapping `"userns-remap": "default"` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` this fixed the error for me.