# Why can't I read from `/proc/timer_list`?

Tags: linux, docker, security, kernel, podman

I'm trying to read from `/proc/timer_list` in a Docker container. I think I'm doing everything right, and yet I get permission denied.

```
$ podman run --privileged ubuntu:wily cat /proc/timer_list
cat: /proc/timer_list: Permission denied
```

I believe that `--privileged` should prevent the container from masking anything, including `/proc/timer_list`.

`findmnt` confirms this; if I understand this output correctly, it means there aren't any masked paths under `/proc`.

```
$ podman run --privileged ubuntu:wily findmnt /proc
TARGET SOURCE FSTYPE OPTIONS
/proc  proc   proc   rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime
```

And obviously, the `cat /proc/timer_list` is running as root.

So what else is needed?

I've tried various versions of ubuntu. I went as far back as `wily` because I'd seen that `timer_list` might have been [removed](https://www.openwall.com/lists/kernel-hardening/2017/02/08/26) around 2017.

This is for a fun little project, that isn't leaving my machine, so things can be wildly insecure.

I have read this related [Stack Overflow thread on reading from `/proc` in `--privileged` containers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56573990/access-to-full-proc-in-docker-container) but it doesn't seem to help me, or perhaps I don't understand it.

---

Thanks to Richard Huxton for the answer. This worked for me on MacOS 12.6 and podman 4.2.1.

```
$ podman machine --stop
$ podman machine set --rootful
$ podman machine start
$ sudo podman run --privileged -it ubuntu:wily
root@f004a8a0229e:/# cat /proc/timer_list
Timer List Version: v0.9
HRTIMER_MAX_CLOCK_BASES: 8
now at 62526451236 nsecs
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `--privileged` flag when you run podman rootless obviously can't give your container privileges you don't have as a normal user.

So unless you can do `cat /proc/timer_list` as your normal user (which the `$` prompt suggests you are) it won't work. I certainly can't access it as my normal user.

So - you'll need to run your podman container as root to access root stuff.

Comment: Bingo. Thank you, I guess I have not grokked the nature of podman.